# What does productive means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Charlie: Let's see what's on the wires.
>
> Joane: Why can't you wait for newspapers like everybody else?
>
> Charlie: 'Cause I think it's **productive** to know today's news today.
>   And it makes me one day smarter than you, which I enjoy as well.

Productive word used in land areas, like productive land means fertile lands which means farmer will get when he use that land. but context is about newspaper & information stuff.

Comment: Did you check the meaning of the word in a dictionary? For example [Cambridge online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/productive) says: "having positive results",  [Oxford Learner's](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/productive?q=productive) "doing or achieving a lot" (syn.  fruitful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it's more efficient to know the news early and not have to wait for the newspapers, which, in fact, talk about yesterday's news rather than today's. On that sentence, efficient would be a good synonym for productive.